# Rails observer callbacks in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, controller, observer-pattern

I have observers set up on my rails app, that observer after_save(campaign).

Basically the observers look for specific tags in the campaign, and if those tags are present, it creates a new record in the "Achievement" model.

What I am trying to do is, in the campaign controller, see if any of these Achievements have been created by the observers, and if so, redirect the user to that Achievement show page.

I'm sure there is an easy function for this that I just don't know about...but what should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no code, i'd assume the following:

Some kind of relationship between `Campaign` and `Achievement`

Based on that you could do it with ruby like:

```
@campain = #however you find the campaign
if @campaign.include?(Achievement.find_by_tag(@tag))
  redirect_to achievements_path
else 
  flash[:error] = "Not this time, dude."
  #something here to redirect if NO achievement
end
```

Comment: hmmm, i think this. It could ALMOST work, if I use the before_save(campaign) in the observer.  The problem comes from, the achievements don't have any references to the tag in their actual database records...the tags are just iterated over in the observers.  Is there a method thats like: Achievement.new? That sees if any achievements have been created recently (instead of Achievement.find_by_tag(@tag))

Comment: Nah, but you could check @campaign.acheievements.last to see when it was created and then do your business with that.  You need to scope it from the campaign, or else you are finding the LAST achievement saved by ALL users and/or campaigns... which won't be what you want.